# How do I create a build for a legacy system?

Tags: perl, build

We are currently maintaining a Perl web application and we are slowly trying to bring it into the modern age.

We want to be able to build our application so that when a new developer comes along we can just give them a copy of the build and they can have a local copy of the application with minimal fuss.

Does anyone have any experience of creating a build for a legacy web application that could offer some pro tips?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "build"?   How does the "legacy" part change your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by authoring an ordinary CPAN distribution, Perl modules go into `lib` etc. This is described in [`perlnewmod`](http://p3rl.org/newmod) and the documents referenced in its section titled *See also*.

Use [Module::Build](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild) as the build system. You extend it for the extra stuff you want to install, for example template files, this is described in the [cookbook](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aCookbook#Adding_new_file_types_to_the_build_process).