# Installing Term::ReadLine::Gnu while the Perl script is running and using the module in the script

Tags: perl, module, installation, readline

I'm writing a program for others to use.  One of the design specs is to use the Term::ReadLine::Gnu Perl library.  Most of the users will not have this installed and I want to install it while the program is running.

So, when the user starts the program they do not have the library installed.  My program will install it for them while they are using the program using the OS package manager.

This is how I'm checking for the module

```
         require Term::ReadLine;

         my $Readline_Support = 1;
         eval { require Term::ReadLine::Gnu }
           or $Readline_Support = 0;
```

I use the $Readline_Support variable to redirect the terminal, use the history file etc.

```
          $OUT = $TERMINAL->OUT if $readline_installed;
          if ($readline_installed)
          {
            # save every answer and default, good or not, to the history file
            $TERMINAL->add_history($Ans);
            $TERMINAL->append_history(1, HIST_FILE);
          }
```

Unfortunately, I get this error when I try to use the history file:

Can't locate object method "using_history" via package "Term::ReadLine::Stub" at ./msi.pl line 618,  line 2.

line 618 is

```
          $TERMINAL->using_history();
```

Which is the first use of the $TERMINAL object.

Has any one had experience with installing Perl modules while the script is running and then using the modules in that same script?

Ok... Thanks to Andy if the module is not installed this works

```
          # I removed the  require Term::ReadLine; here
          my $Readline_Support = 1;
          eval { require Term::ReadLine::Gnu }
            or $Readline_Support = 0;
```

below in the code

```
            if ($readline_installed)
            {
              # Required for the dynamic loading of Term::ReadLine::Gnu
              require Term::ReadLine;

              $TERMINAL = Term::ReadLine->new ('ProgramName')
                 if $Interactive or $Brief
            }
```

Now, however, the check for the installed mod always fails, I think because

```
            require Term::ReadLine::Gnu;
```

needs

```
            require Term::ReadLine;
```

early in the code, like the old

```
     require Term::ReadLine;

     my $Readline_Support = 1;
     eval { require Term::ReadLine::Gnu }
       or $Readline_Support = 0;
```

Comment: `require Term::ReadLine::Gnu` is always going to fail, there's a check in the code that disallows it. Try running `perl -e 'eval { require Term::ReadLine::Gnu } or print "require failed:\n$@\n"'` with and without the module installed. But see my updated answer for a way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in the code for `Term::ReadLine` that it determines which implementation it is going to use at load time, as opposed to when `new` is called. So I would suggest the following sequence:

1. test for availability of `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` just like you are currently, but before loading any `ReadLine` modules
2. install `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` if not present
3. `require Term::ReadLine`
4. create your object with `Term::ReadLine->new`

Things are made more complicated because `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` throws an error on an attempt to load it directly with `use` or `require`, so the straightforward `eval` test fails even when it's installed. One way to deal with that is to parse `$@`, but I don't like parsing diagnostic messages because there's a risk they may change over time. Deleting from `%INC` doesn't seem great either, but should work as long as the error on a direct load of `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` doesn't go away.

```
my $readline_installed = 1;
unless (eval { require Term::ReadLine::Gnu; }) {
    # Term::ReadLine::Gnu throws an error that it can't be loaded directly,
    # even when it's installed.
    $readline_installed = exists ($INC{"Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm"});

    # Needed so that it will be reloaded after installation
    delete $INC{"Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm"};
}

unless ($readline_installed) {
    print "Installing Term::ReadLine::Gnu\n";
    # ...
}

require Term::ReadLine;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new ("app");
$term->addhistory ("blah");
print $term->readline ("> "), "\n";
```

Comment: I think that general approach will work, but `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` throws an error on an attempt to load it directly, so it'll be a bit more involved. I'll work on something more complete.

Comment: Thanks, that works, yet now if the module is installed then it will not load the mod.

Comment: @bitbucket It will not load after installing, even with the updated code? Do you have the `delete $INC{...}`? It's working for me with perl 5.10.1 on linux.

Comment: Nice, works great.  I saw some other code that changed $INC.  Now I think I'm getting a better idea of use, require and %INC.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Most of the users will not have this installed and I want to install it while the program is running.

You're swimming against the flow here. No one else does it this way, and changing a system after installation would also upset most system admins I know.

Simply declare the dependency, so when your program is installed, T::R::G is also installed. I link to the pertinent documentation in [How do I create a build for a legacy system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469314/how-do-i-create-a-build-for-a-legacy-system/4469461#4469461).

The toolchain gives you already all the necessary bits to make this painless for everyone who is involved, do learn about it.

Comment: some of the systems will not have access to cpan.  The idea is to only use the OS package manager.  I like your idea... I'll look into it.  I do give the sys admins the choice to not do it.

Comment: Going the proper way makes packaging super easy: cpanspec, dh-make-pm. As I said before, every tool already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn from the "cpan" command itself. cpan can install (upgrade) himself and reload all used modules afterward. That should be a good starting point for learning.